# Calling a subclass attribute from the main class using Visual Code Java

Tags: java, oop

So I can run my code from cmd, I edit using sublime text, but now I´m required to use Visual Code Studio and this software can´t seem to call any subclass porperties from the main method, Visual Code can't seem to handle this line: (Healer)n.get(i)).getHealer()

When I use the subclass getter it doesnt give an error message, however when I try to create an object for the subclass I get the following: "The public type Healer must be defined in its own file"

```
// n is an ArrayList with objects and this iteration is in the superclass

for(int i = 0; i<= n.size()-1; i++){
   if(Healer.class.isInstance(n.get(i))){
          System.out.println(((Healer)n.get(i)).getHealer());
   }
}
```

```
// and here's the constructor for the subclass that I'm calling from the superclass

public class Healer extends Hero{
    int healer;

    Healer(String c, String a, String b, int d, int e, int o){
        super(c,a,b,d,e);
        this.setHealer(o);
    }
    public void setHealer(int o){
        this.healer = o;
    }
    public int getHealer(){
        return healer;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code. The rules here are defined by the Java language no matter which editor you use. For us to help you, please [edit] your question to show the exact error message that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code and everything to do with the rules of Java. The error message is very clear about what you need to do:

> The public type Healer must be defined in its own file

Either put `class Healer` in its own file or remove the `public` modifier.

Comment: I mean cmd does run it

Comment: @squirosv What do you mean? What commands do you type in `cmd` that give a different behavior than what you see in Visual Studio Code>?

Comment: For  Visual Studio Code I have to take off the public access modifier, and cmd doesn´t run it without it